# Can't start Android Studio Layout Inspector: "Unexpected error: empty view hierarchy"

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, layout-inspector

Can't seem to launch Layout Inspector on Android Studio 3.0 (Canary 3)

When connected to my device and app running, choosing Tools > Android > Layout Inspector comes up with the following error dialog:

**"Error obtaining view hierarchy: Unexpected error: empty view hierarchy"**

[image]

Any setup I'm missing? I have Developer Options enabled on the device.

Comment: Have you tried using a non Canary version as well?

Comment: Having the same problem in Android Studio 3.1

Comment: Almost 2019 and they still have not fixed this frigging problem.

Answer (score 11):

In general I've this behavior when something is "moving" in the view so the layout inspector cannot retrieve a simple layout, that's why pausing a video will work but if you have something more complex like camera preview or Google Map is harder, not sure how to work around this

Comment: Thanks! For me it was Lotty animation. So I changed animation scale to 0 to stop it

Comment: Yes, same to me. A Lottie animation caused the view to "change" all the time.

Answer (score 6):

If you have `ViewTreeObserver` in your code to measure a view's width/height, and you're changing some width/height/padding/etc. according to a result you are getting from `addOnPreDrawListener` of ViewTreeObserver;

Just comment inside `onPreDraw` or comment all code related to `ViewTreeObserver`.

Answer (score 4):

I can't launch my hierarchy viewer while playing video. Once I pause the video, it works!

Comment: I happened to meet that error as well on production Android Studio 3.0, in an activity after an activity having a live preview from camera. So far I haven't been able to come up with a solution to this

Answer (score 3):

This could be related to your Android version. For example, in my case, this error occurs on Genymotion on Android 4. After moving to Android 5 this error gone.

Comment: Well said. I changed from Android 6 to 7. Problem solved!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had two devices connected to add, one device and an emulator. And I had to make sure only one device is connected. Then it worked. I was on Android Studio 3.2 Canary.

Answer (score 2):

What I tried and did NOT work:

- kill adb process and tried it again
- clearing cache and restart
- uninstalling the app, cleaning the build and building it again
- disconnect the device and plug it back in

Finally I managed to solve it by **turning off developer options and then turning it on + enable usb debugging**.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem on Android Studio v2.3.3, problem was related to CountDownTimer Object, somehow it cause problem (probably because of onTick method).
After commenting it, I could normally use Layout Inspector.
Maybe you use something similar in your code, try to comment it out and see if if works.

Comment: Disable all timer make it work. Thank for your suggest!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

Could not capture hierarchy on Emulator.

I used a real device and it worked fine.

Comment: The opposite for me, emulator worked but device didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my device from a Nexus 6 to a Pixel XL. Then it worked.

So try and change your device and see if that fixes the issue.